# Sender cannot be shared between threads safely when using question mark operator

Tags: rust, error-handling

Sending a struct containing a `Sender` through a channel and using the question mark to handle errors, Rust complains about `Sender<..>` not implementing Sync.
Without the question mark, it doesn't.

So, is the `Sync` trait expected from the `Sender`?
Not understanding the question mark operator in detail, I assume an `anyhow::Error` is being constructed - but why would the `Sender` end up in the error object?

(My application has one database thread that handles all queries and communicates via channels)
Here's the code:

```
|db: Db| -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let (res_tx, res_rx) =  mpsc::channel::<Result<Vec<Row>>>();

    db.send(database_handler::Request::Query {
        query: "select name from actions",
        params: Vec::new(),
        result: res_tx,
    })?; // dis be line 35
}
```

Here's the error:

```
error[E0277]: `Sender<Result<Vec<postgres::Row>, anyhow::Error>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/events.rs:35:6
   |
35 |             })?;
   |               ^ `Sender<Result<Vec<postgres::Row>, anyhow::Error>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `SendError<Request<'_>>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `Sender<Result<Vec<postgres::Row>, anyhow::Error>>`
   = help: the following other types implement trait `FromResidual<R>`:
             <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Result<Infallible, E>>>
             <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Yeet<E>>>
note: required because it appears within the type `Request<'_>`
  --> src/database.rs:39:10
   |
39 | pub enum Request<'a> {
   |          ^^^^^^^
   = note: required because it appears within the type `SendError<Request<'_>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `From<SendError<Request<'_>>>` for `anyhow::Error`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, SendError<Request<'_>>>>` for `Result<(), anyhow::Error>`
```

And these are the involved types:

```
type Db<'a> = Sender<database_handler::Request<'a>>;

type ParamsType<'a> = Vec<&'a (dyn ToSql + Sync)>;

pub enum Request<'a> {
  Query { query: &'static str, params: ParamsType<'a>, result: Sender<Result<Vec<Row>>> },
  QueryOne { query: &'static str, params: ParamsType<'a>, result: Sender<Result<Option<Row>>> },
  Execute { query: &'static str, params: ParamsType<'a>, result: Sender<Result<u64>> },
}
```

Comment: You're right that an `anyhow::Error` is being constructed, but - from what? Since `Sender::send()` takes ownership of the value you give it, its error type includes the original value which it "returns back" to you in case it failed to send it. Therefore `anyhow::Error` gets constructed from `SendError<Query>`, which is not `Sync` because `Query` contains a (different) `Sender`, which is itself not `Sync`. Once you know this, you can sort of see the error message telling you this, too. The fix is to use something like `db.send(...).map_err(|_| anyhow!("receiver is gone"))?`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!
Very useful `map_err` there - it looks so mundane in the docs...

I've settled on `.map_err(|error| { anyhow!(error.to_string())})?;` to preserve the error message.

Comment: I've now posted an answer. As for preserving the error message, I intentionally didn't do that because this code is not dealing with a system-level error where the underlying system error message (such as "permission denied" or "file not found") comes useful for diagnostics and debugging. In this case the only possible reason why sending would fail would be for the receiver to be dropped, so a custom error message makes as much sense as the original one (or more). If you are sure that the thread that will receive the message will be live, this is also an acceptable place to use `.unwrap()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that an `anyhow::Error` is being constructed, but - from what? Since `Sender::send()` takes ownership of the value you give it, the error it returns when it fails to send includes the original value, allowing you to retry sending later or in a different manner. So your `anyhow::Error` gets constructed from `SendError<Query>` that contains a `Query`.

The `Sync` requirement comes from `anyhow::Error` itself being `Send` and `Sync` (because it's useful to move error to a different thread), so its `From` implementation must require the same of the source error. In your case the source error is `SendError<Query>` which is not `Sync` because it contains `Query` whose `result` field contains a (different) `Sender`, which not `Sync`.

Once aware of this, you can see the error message telling you this, too. The fix is to replace `db.send(...)?` with something like `db.send(...).map_err(|_| anyhow!("receiver is gone"))`. Also, you'll need an explicit `Ok(())` at the end of the closure.